# Listview does not contain a definition for selecteditems

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms.I want to remove the selected item in listview after clicking Remove button.

My xaml

```
 <ListView x:Name="ProductsListView"
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          BackgroundColor="#ecf0f1"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Margin="6,4,6,4"
                             BackgroundColor="White">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Text="Item ID" Margin="25,10,4,4" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black"  />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding retail_modified_item_id}"  Margin="25,10,4,4" TextColor="Black" FontSize="12" />
                                </StackLayout>

                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Text="Name" Margin="25,2,8,4" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding name}" Margin="32,1,8,4" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" />
                                    <Switch IsToggled="false"  Margin="210,2,2,2" Toggled="Switch_Toggled" />
                                </StackLayout>

                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Text="OldPrice"  Margin="25,2,8,4" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding old_price}" Margin="32,1,8,4" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" />
                                </StackLayout>

                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Text="NewPrice" Margin="25,2,8,4" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding new_price}" Margin="32,1,8,4" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" />
                                </StackLayout>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

My cs code

```
private void reject(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        foreach (var v in ProductsListView.SelectedItems)
        {
           ProductsListView.ItemSelected.Remove(v);
        }
        DisplayAlert("Rejected","Request Rejected!!", "OK");
    }
```

I am getting this error:

> listview does not contain a definition for selecteditem, ItemSelected

Comment: If your issue has been completed with answer below , you can mark as completed my answer.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: @G.hakim i want to delete the selected data after clicking reject button.i attached the delete code in reject function.but it throws error  " listview does not contain a definition for selecteditem , ItemSelected"

Comment: Can you point out the line of code where this happens

Comment: foreach (var v in ProductsListView.SelectedItems)
        
           ProductsListView.ItemSelected.Remove(v);     // selectedItem and itemSelected

Answer (score 2):

You can try cast it to ProductListView,

```
var selectedItems = (ListView/* or ProductListView*/)sender; //-> you need casting to access it.
```

> And you can change list view item source

```
public void reject(your_list_of_model_type your_list_of_model)
{
   your_list_of_model.RemoveRange(selectedItems);
   ProductListView.ItemSource = your_list_of_model;
}
```

> Solution 2 :

Here is what you could do :

This be my model class :

```
public class Item  
{  
   public string ItemName { get; set; }  
   public string ItemDetails { get; set; }  
}
```

And in my XAML or you can write this in code as well, bind to the Command Parameter of your Item template :

```
<Button Text="Delete" CommandParameter="{Binding ItemName}" Clicked="DeleteClicked"></Button>
Full Item Template will be like below :

<ListView.ItemTemplate>  
            <DataTemplate>  
               <ViewCell>  
                  <ViewCell.View>  
                     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">  
                        <Label Text="{Binding ItemName}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="30"></Label>  
                        <Button Text="Delete" CommandParameter="{Binding ItemName}" Clicked="DeleteClicked">        
                        </Button>  
                     </StackLayout>  
                  </ViewCell.View>  
               </ViewCell>  
            </DataTemplate>  
         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And in you code file you can do this :

```
public void DeleteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
   var item = (Xamarin.Forms.Button)sender;  
   Item listitem = (from itm in allItems 
                    where itm.ItemName == item.CommandParameter.ToString() 
                    select itm)
                   .FirstOrDefault<Item>();  
   allItems.Remove(listitem);  
}
```

IMPORTANT : This would only delete the item from the bound collection. To delete it from the original list you need to use `ObservableCollection`

Comment: can you explain this code i can't understand.From this code how can i get all selected value ?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'ProductsListView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   ,                              The event 'ListView.ItemSelected' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= 
i am getting these 2 errors

Comment: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ListView' because 'ListView' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'  - foreach (var item in selectedItems ) ERROR IN SELECTEDITEMS .....                        The event 'ListView.ItemSelected' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=  ERROR IN  ProductsListView.ItemSelected.Remove(item);      Actually why these errors are happening what mistake i did ?

Comment: updated again my answer , you need get selected items and remove them your source and you can give updated source to ListView.ItemSource it will be changes.

Comment: private void reject(object sender, EventArgs args) // Is args is your_list_of_model?  what is your_list_of_model_type & your_list_of_model

Comment: They are your model which you give the ListView.ItemSource

Comment: Updated by new solution

Answer (score 0):

You can add all the toggled items to a list, suppose `selectedItems`. And when you click `REJECT` button, delete the `selectedItems` from the datasource of listview.

The full code is like this:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Button Text="APPROVE" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Button Text="REJECT" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Clicked="reject"/>
        <ListView x:Name="ProductsListView" 
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          BackgroundColor="#ecf0f1"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="6,4,6,4"
                             BackgroundColor="White">

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding name}" Margin="32,1,8,4" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" />
                                <Switch IsToggled="false"  Margin="210,2,2,2" Toggled="Switch_Toggled" />
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding retail_modified_item_id}"  Margin="25,10,4,4" TextColor="Black" FontSize="12" />
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="OldPrice"  Margin="25,2,8,4" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding old_price}" Margin="32,1,8,4" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" />
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="NewPrice" Margin="25,2,8,4" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding new_price}" Margin="32,1,8,4" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" />
                            </StackLayout>

                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        ObservableCollection<ItemModel> allItems = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();
        List<ItemModel> selectedItems = new List<ItemModel>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeData();
            ProductsListView.ItemsSource = allItems;
        }

        private void reject(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var v in selectedItems)
            {
                allItems.Remove(v);
            }
            DisplayAlert("Rejected", "Request Rejected!!", "OK");
        }

        private void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
        {
            var switch1 = (Switch)sender;
            var item = (ItemModel)switch1.BindingContext;

            var isSelected = !item.selected;

            if (isSelected)
            {
                selectedItems.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                selectedItems.Remove(item);
            }
        }

        private void InitializeData() {
            allItems.Add(new ItemModel { name = "Onion Rings, Medium",
                retail_modified_item_id = 1000630,
                old_price = 1.29,
                new_price = 9.45,
                selected = false
            });

            allItems.Add(new ItemModel
            {
                name = "Hashbrowns",
                retail_modified_item_id = 1000739,
                old_price = 0.99,
                new_price = 8.5,
                selected = false
            });

            allItems.Add(new ItemModel
            {
                name = "Amstel Light, Single",
                retail_modified_item_id = 1002038,
                old_price = 3.5,
                new_price = 18,
                selected = false
            });

        }
    }
```

ItemModel.cs:

```
class ItemModel
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int retail_modified_item_id { get; set; }
        public double old_price { get; set; }
        public double new_price { get; set; }
        public bool selected { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: you must refresh the listview for see changes